# Request takes longer than maximum time and I get error 500

Tags: c#, load-balancing

My loadbalancer is set to maximum time - 120 seconds.
However when I process big data, it takes more time than that and I get error 500 - Service is temporarily unavailable.

How can I handle this issue?

Comment: Can't you make your processing in another thread so that the main thread can still ping the load balancer to say "I'm alive" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way of doing this is offloading the long running job to a separate "job server"  and returning a web page immediately.

The "job server" can update job status in the database when completed or with progress as the job runs, and your web clients can poll the web server using AJAX or during normal page loads, looking for jobs marked as completed in the database and displaying a link to the result.

That way, no web request will take very long time at all and the client can go on starting more jobs or go on navigating the site while the job runs, even if your jobs run for hours.

Comment: Note that for this kind of "synchronization", I would highly recommend ZooKeeper over any kind of database storage, mostly for the "watching" capabiity, which avoid database polling.

Comment: @C4stor Agreed, if the polling volume is big, you could keep it out of the database using appfabric cache/memcached or ZooKeeper, and also "better" methods than plain polling like websockets/long polling. The important takeaway is that it's not always a good idea to run a long running process on the web request thread and block the user.